# CNTK: csv column format in example 104

Tags: python, csv, pandas, cntk

In CNTK example (CNTK_104_Finance_Timeseries_Basic_with_Pandas_Numpy)
the data look likes:
    [get_stock_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTE32.png)

I have try pd.read_csv to read my own csv data:

```
url = 'http://localhost/csv/SPY0.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(url)
data.tail(5)
```

...the result:
[pandas.read_csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nacRy.png)

Question is: How csv column format like "get_stock_data" does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add parameter `index_col` for read column to `index` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Also you can convert `index` to `DatetimeIndex` by `parse_dates`.

```
#convert first column to index (python counts from 0)
data = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0])

#convert column with name Date to index
data = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=['Date'], parse_dates=['Date'])
```

Another solution is use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
data = pd.read_csv(url)
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
data = data.set_index('Date')
```